# Multiple websites in the same S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to host multiple websites with similar subdomains in the same S3 bucket under different folders with a cloudfront distribution that redirects to each folder.

Suppose my bucket is example.com and I want to host my angular website at sub1.example.com and another one at sub2.example.com. I have created folders for each of them in the bucket named sub1 and sub2. I have also created cloudfront distributions with the origin name points to the S3 bucket and added the origin path to the corresponding folder.

After doing this, if I try to go to sub1.example.com it works fine. But if I try sub1.example.com/home I get a 404 page with Code: NoSuchKey. I think this is because S3 is trying to look for sub1/home in the bucket rather than serving the angular file in the sub1 folder.

Is this something that can corrected? I need to do this with a single S3 bucket.

Comment: S3 bucket for store the doc and files its not for website hosting , what you want to do? 
NoSuchKey error comes when you type wrong file name which are not exist in bucket

Comment: You can put a `.` in a bucket name. Why exactly can’t you create `sub1.mybucket` and `sub2.mybucket` as separate buckets?

Comment: @PriyankaSankhala S3 can be used for website hosting, as long as any rendering code is client-side: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

Comment: @MatthewPope I need to make lots of such websites and have already run into the S3 bucket's limit of 100. If this does not work I'll need to request for more buckets or manage this through multiple AWS accounts is what I've read.

Comment: You can request increases up to the account limit of 1000 buckets. Beyond that, you may want to consider using Route 53 to set up your own domain name with sub domains for each website.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fix the issue by following these [instructions](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://medium.com/@peatiscoding/here-is-how-easy-it-is-to-deploy-an-angular-spa-single-page-app-as-a-static-website-using-s3-and-6aa446db38ef&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1574836216917000&usg=AFQjCNHdvhJQLfN0DECNcm1mlrTMPyzcWg). I was able to fix the issue after adding **Default Root Object** when creating the cloudfront distribution and adding custom error responses in the cloudfront distribution that redirects **404** and **403** error codes to **index.html**.